# Нужны ли в предложении запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

«Сопоставление положений ст. 75 УК с одной стороны и ст. 761 УК – с другой позволяет сделать вывод о невозможности включения последней в общую систему норм».
Закралось сомнение, нужны ли здесь запятые?

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны, с другой стороны - это вводная конструкция. Поэтому в Вашем предложении нужно поставить знаки так:***«Сопоставление положений ст. 75 УК, с одной стороны, и ст. 761 УК – с другой, позволяет сделать вывод о невозможности включения последней в общую систему норм».*** 
Тире в вашем предложении ставится, так как вводное словосочетание образует неполную конструкцию(пропущено слово "со стороны").

Но выражение "с одной стороны, с другой стороны" может быть и членом предложения. В ПАС Лопатина об этом сказано так:

Вводные сочетания с одной стороны, с другой стороны выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми: ...Генерал не хотел допускать и того, чтобы дивизия его перестала существовать. С другой стороны, он знал, что выполнит свой долг до конца (Фад.); С одной стороны, ты прав, но, с другой стороны, ты должен принять во внимание и мою точку зрения (газ.). При пропуске слова стороны ставится тире: С одной стороны, знания студента были глубокими, с другой — они оказались очень односторонними. Ср. случаи, когда с одной стороны и с другой стороны — члены предложения: Подул сильный ветер, детей позвали в комнаты старика, — и они с ним сидели на теплой лежанке — Ваня с одной стороны, Люба с другой (М. Г.); Теперь на него смотрели уже со всех сторон — и не только смотрели. С одной стороны к нему приближалась хозяйка с длинной палкой в руке, с другой — господин с бакенбардами (Пелев.).